# Area of intersection of two Annulus

Tags: circles, plane-curves

Given two separate annulus with centers $[C_1,C_2]$ and their corresponding radii being $[R_1,r_1]$ and $[R_2,r_2]$ respectively, larger radius being $R$. There are methods to look at whether they are overlapping or not. If they overlap how to find the overlapping area. Is there any close form expression for it? 
equation of first annulus

$r_1^2<(x-x_{c1})^2 + (y-y_{c1})^2 <R_1^2$

equation of second annulus

$r_2^2<(x-x_{c2})^2 + (y-y_{c2})^2 <R_2^2$

If there are three circles overlapping, we get overlapping area as solution to set of 4 in-equations by least squares approach(Though we don't end up getting total area but, area within tangents of circles ).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I tried the area bound by $4<(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2<9$ and $1<(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2<25$. This turned out to be very ugly and long (below). In general probably there one can find a formula ... 
\begin{align}
Area&=\frac{1}{2} \left[8 \sqrt{6}-3 \sqrt{91}-4 \pi +25 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{625} \left(63 \sqrt{6}-142\right)\right)-9 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{50} \left(9-4
   \sqrt{91}\right)\right)+25 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{250} \left(4 \sqrt{91}-41\right)\right)+9 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{50} \left(9+4 \sqrt{91}\right)\right)-8 \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{25} \left(3+8 \sqrt{6}\right)\right)+18 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{50} \left(9+4 \sqrt{91}\right)\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{7}\right)+25 \csc
   ^{-1}(5)+25 \csc ^{-1}\left(\frac{1250}{69 \sqrt{91}-164 \sqrt{6}}\right)\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes; here is a rough outline of the argument. Let the first ring be bounded by inner circle $C_1$ and outer circle $C_2$, and let the second ring be bounded by inner circle $C_3$ and outer circle $C_4$. Then the desired area is given as follows:

- Compute area lying between $C_2$ and $C_4$;
- Subtract off area lying between $C_1$ and $C_4$;
- Subtract off area lying between $C_2$ and $C_3$.

So it boils down to computing the area lying between two circles meeting at two points. That area can be computed by viewing the region as the union of two pieces, each piece consisting of a sector of one of the circles minus a triangle.

Note: the above solution depends on the positioning of the two rings; I'm assuming that the rings are positioned roughly as in your diagram.