# Area between 2 rings

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I would like to know if is possible calculate the area between 2 rings with opposite centers and the same radius, that is:

$$r_1^2<(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<r_2^2$$
$$r_1^2<(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2<r_2^2$$

I think that depend on the relation between center and radius, but I'm not sure.

I'm working on...

Edit:

This is an example

$$4<(x-1){}^2+(y-2){}^2<8$$

$$4<(x+1){}^2+(y+2){}^2<8$$

[image: Ejemplo]

[image]

Comment: I think if you added a picture to illustrate the area in which you are interested, that would add greatly to the value of this question.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "between". If you mean the area of overlap between the 2 rings then you will have a different result than if you mean the area not covered by either ring but "within" the inner circle of both rings. If you want the second of these, then you can ignore the larger radii of each circle, as you'd simply be calculating the overlap of 2 circles

Comment: I want to calculate the area formed by the points that verify the 4 inequalities at the same time (when is not the empty set).

Comment: It seems to me "the opposite" is a complete red herring.  Any two centers would do the same.  wolog you can assume they are opposites, or assume they are both on x or y axis, or assume one is at the origin, if it will make your calculations easier.  But where the centers are will have no geometric bearing on the area.

Comment: @fleablood Well if they have the same center then this problem sort of breaks down.

Comment: @fleablood  Yes, may be ... if both rings are not the same center

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337347/area-of-intersection-of-two-annulus?rq=1

Comment: @AshvinSwaminathan Hmm, I could swear I wrote "any two *different* centers"...  Oh, well. Still $(0,0)$ is opposite $(0,0)$ so the distinction isn't mine to make.....

Comment: Also useful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html